# Make a delete button for RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my first app in Kotlin, but I don't think I am understanding well the logic. I am trying to make a delete button for every single element in a List with Recycler View:

my MusicianRecyclerAdapter:

```
package com.example.genremusicians

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.genremusicians.Models.MusicianInfo
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_musician_list.view.*

class MusicianRecyclerAdapter (private val context: Context, private val musicians:List<MusicianInfo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicianRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val  layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val deleteButton = itemView.deleteButton
        val textGenre = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTitle)
        val textMusician = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewText)
        var musicianPosition = 0
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                val intent = Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MUSICIAN_POSITION,musicianPosition)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
        init {
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener{
                val intent = Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.removeExtra(EXTRA_MUSICIAN_POSITION)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_musician_list,parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return musicians.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var musician = musicians[position]
        holder.textGenre.text = musician.genre?.title
        holder.textMusician.text = musician.name
        holder.musicianPosition = position
    }
}
```

and this is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.genremusicians

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import com.example.genregenres.Models.DataManager
import com.example.genremusicians.Models.GenreInfo
import com.example.genremusicians.Models.MusicianInfo
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var musicianPosition = POSITION_NOT_SET
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var adapterGenres = ArrayAdapter<GenreInfo>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            DataManager.genres.values.toList()
        )

        adapterGenres.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line)
        spinnerGenre.adapter = adapterGenres

        musicianPosition = savedInstanceState?.getInt(EXTRA_MUSICIAN_POSITION, POSITION_NOT_SET)
            ?: intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_MUSICIAN_POSITION, POSITION_NOT_SET)


        if (musicianPosition != POSITION_NOT_SET) {
            displayMusician()
        } else {
            createMusician()
        }

    }

    private fun createMusician() {
        DataManager.musicians.add(MusicianInfo())
        musicianPosition = DataManager.musicians.lastIndex
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        saveMusician()
    }

    private fun saveMusician() {
        val musician = DataManager.musicians[musicianPosition]
        musician.name = editTextName.text.toString()
        musician.album = editTextAlbum.text.toString()
        musician.genre = spinnerGenre.selectedItem as GenreInfo
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putInt(EXTRA_MUSICIAN_POSITION, musicianPosition)
    }

    private fun displayMusician() {
        val musician = DataManager.musicians[musicianPosition]
        editTextName.setText(musician.name)
        editTextAlbum.setText(musician.album)
        val genrePosition = DataManager.genres.values.indexOf(musician.genre)
        spinnerGenre.setSelection(genrePosition)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            R.id.action_next -> {
                MoveNext()
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        if (musicianPosition >= DataManager.musicians.lastIndex) {
            var item = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_next)
            if (item != null) {
                item.icon = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_block_24)
                item.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun invalidateOptionsMenu() {
        super.invalidateOptionsMenu()
    }

    private fun MoveNext() {
        musicianPosition++
        displayMusician()
        invalidateOptionsMenu()
    }
}
```

I have my Data from a file I created to start learning, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong to create a delete button, and how I should do it. Thank you all

Comment: why don't you put the button in the cardView xml file and then access it through the onBindViewHolder() method like so: holder.itemview.myDeleteButton.setOnClickListener{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set an on click event to delete you must use the code below and in your adapter:

```
private var onClickListener : OnClickListener? = null

fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener){
    this.onClickListener = onClickListener
}

interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(position: Int){
    }
}
```

You can then create a function to remove items in the recyclerview, this will remove the item at the specified position in the list and also notify the recylerview that an item ha been removed so it will update:

```
private fun removeItem(position: Int){
    list.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}
```

This will allow you to call the onClick function when you create an instance of the interface. You must have a delete button in the xml file of your item view which you can then set an onClickListener for the button in the onBindViewHolder like so :

```
holder.itemView.btn_delete.setOnClickListener {
                if(onClickListener != null){
                    onClickListener!!.onClick(position)
                    removeItem(position)
                }
            }
```

Comment: thank you for your complete answer, the main Issue I was handling was that I didnt declare the mutable list, it was like : private val musicians:List<MusicianInfo>). after it implementing what you said was amazing, thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help, would be much appreciated if you marked my answer as correct :)

Comment: I am so sorry, I thought I did, thank you again and sorry again